# Google Custom Search API results inaccurate

Tags: google-api

We've been using the Google Custom Search API for some time to return regular Google Search results within our application. It has been working and we track ranking history and the past two months a certain site (www.leaderford.com) is showing up as not being displayed within the top 30 sites on the returned results from the API, though it is showing first when searched through Google with keywords "Ford Dealer Clemson". This specific site is not showing up for any of the keywords which they historically have been ranked #1.

Any ideas about why the discrepancy would occur?